# Retrieve a CSV file generated from a table by javascript

Tags: javascript, http, csv, curl

First, let me say that I am not familiar with the terminology so, if you see something, by all means, help me improve the wording.

What I want to do is retrieve a CSV file that is generated by a website, apparently based on a table.

The site in question has two drop boxes from which one can select the queries and then, based on `*onchange=*', a search is made and a table is filled.

With the table filled, a button appears, which can then be pressed and the CSV file, containing the fields, is offered to download.

After poking around with the page, I was able to find and construct the URL responsible to retrieve the CSV file. It is something like:

```
http://www.example.com/exportCSV.action?field1=3&field2=5
```

The problem is, if I try to `**curl**' it, a empty CSV file is retrieved, with just the headers. So, I think that the actual content must be inside the table which is filled using the normal web interface.

The last call from the javascript function that generates the CSV is:

```
window.open("exportCSV.action?"+fields)
```

Is there a way to satisfy the initial search so, when I try to **curl** the `*CSV url*' I can get a filled CSV, and not a empty one?

Answer (score 0):

This rather sounds like that web site is not accepting your cURL request. Some try to limit their services to “real” browsers only.

Try using a debugging tool like FireBug to have a look at the actual data that the JavaScript sends and receives over the network.

I assume you are doing your cURL call right? Passing parameters, especially on the command line, can be a bit tricky. Make sure you escape the URL correctly, for example with single quotes:

```
curl 'http://www.example.com/exportCSV.action?field1=3&field2=5'
```

Else, the `&` character and possibly the question mark as well might get interpreted by your shell.

Comment: Well, the curl call returns the supposed CSV with just the headers, so it is returning something. What lacks is the content.  

Sorry, but what do you mean by "look at the actual data that the JavaScript sends and receives"? I actually used FireBug to find the javascript call.  

Finally, I am calling curl the same way you're, just using " instead of '.

Comment: I mean using FireBug’s “Network” tab to see the request and response headers and data. If that doesn’t help, I’m afraid I’m currently out of clues.

Comment: Good idea. I tried it but nothing seems to fly when I push the export button. That means that the actual exportation is made at the client, doesn't it?

Comment: You know, all of this would be a lot less guesswork if you could provide us with a demo or a link to the site you are talking about.